# how to make nginx only redirect requests from sepcific server and pass other requests to their original servers like fiddler?

Tags: nginx, fiddler

I am trying to make nginx have two functions like fiddler does:

1、Redirect requests from data.abc.com to 127.0.0.1:9000

2、Pass all other requests to their original servers

my nginx.conf is:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       8008;
        server_name   data.abc.com;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
             proxy_pass   https://127.0.0.1:9000/;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
             proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        }
    }
}
```

However, right now every request via port 8008 is redirected, it seems like `server_name` doesn't work, how to make other requests go to original server?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is to redirect all request to `https://127.0.0.1:9000`

Add 2 different server block like follows

1) Redirect `data.abc.com` to `https://127.0.0.1:9000`

```
server {
    listen       8008;
    server_name   data.abc.com;
    return 301 https://127.0.0.1:9000$request_uri
  }
```

2) Serve request for another website:

```
server {
    listen       8008 default_server;;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
}
```